# NSWindow setFrame very laggy

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, grand-central-dispatch, nswindow

My application is a video window that follows another application window. I'm capturing the screen, find the location of the other application and moves mine accordingly. I have a tracking thread that always capturing and tracking for the right position and if it has been changed dispatches a call for updating the position on the main thread:

```
void tracingThread()
{
    while(true)
    {
        captureAndTrack();
        if(positionChanged)
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ setWindowPos(); });
        }
    }
}

void setWindowPos()
{
    [window setFrame:_newFrame display:YES];
}
```

Everything works fine except for the fact that setFrame is very laggy when dragging the other app. My guess is this is because the amount of the events being dispatched. But maybe there is something else. Any ideas how can I improve the performance?

Comment: how often is setWindowPos() called?

Comment: @Max approximately 40 times a second. (captureAndTrack takes 25 mSec)